# Alter python descriptor

Tags: python, descriptor

I've this python descriptor:

```
# Date Descriptor
class DateAttribute():
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, value):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if type(value) is not datetime.date: 
            raise TypeError('A date value is expected')
        self.value = value
```

and a class D that use this descriptor:

```
class D:
    thisdate = DateAttribute()
```

I use this class as:

```
x = D()
x.thisdate = datetime.date(2012, 9, 12)
```

I wish to extend the descriptor to give me formatted results in some ways. Es.

```
x.thisdate.format1
>>> '2012 9 12'
x.thisdate.format2
>>> '2012___9___12'
x.thisdate.format3
>>> '2012####9####12'
.....
```

I could do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Only if the descriptor returns an object with the `format1`, `format2` etc... attribute (or properties). I.e. `x.thisdate` will **not** return a string

Comment: (The suggestions to just not do this with a descriptor are better.)

Comment: Also, if your descriptor is your actual use case, you could just use Enthought Traits.

Comment: Unless you have affirmative reason to use a descriptor, just use an attribute: `x.thisdate = datetime.date(…)`. As you have it, you've made a class DateAttribute that does absolutely nothing. A poor reason for using a descriptor is "because that's how I had to do it in Java/C++ and I haven't understood why Python doesn't have private instance variables."

Answer (score 4):

Add the `formatX` properties to your class and format accordingly:

```
class DateAttribute:
    ...

    @property
    def format1 (self): return self.value.strftime (SOMEFORMAT)

    @property
    def format2 (self): return self.value.strftime (SOMEOTHERFORMAT)
```

For the strftime format strings, [see the datetime documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Works like this:

```
thisdate = DateAttribute (datetime.date (2012, 9, 12) )
print (thisdate.format1)
```

EDIT:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import datetime

class DateAttribute:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        print ('initing')
        self.value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, value):
        print ('getting')
        if not self.value: return self.value
        return FormattedDate (self.value.year, self.value.month, self.value.day)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print ('setting')
        if not isinstance (value, datetime.date): raise TypeError('A date value is expected')
        self.value = value


class FormattedDate (datetime.date):
    @property
    def format1 (self): return self.strftime ('%Y==%m==%d')

class D:
    thisdate = DateAttribute ()

d = D ()
print (d.thisdate)
d.thisdate = datetime.date (2013, 1, 1)
print (d.thisdate)
print (d.thisdate.format1)
```

Produces this output:

```
initing
getting
None
setting
getting
2013-01-01
getting
2013==01==01
```

Comment: If I use your code: x.thisdate.format I receive AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'format1'

Comment: and then how should I choose?

Comment: Ok. In your example you use property when descritor is initialized. But i I want to use them in an instance of class D ?

Comment: I run your code ad receive: `initing
<__main__.DateAttribute instance at 0x7f116737c0e0>
2013-01-01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aaa.py", line 32, in <module>
    print (d.thisdate.format1)
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'format1'`

Comment: The exact code (second snippet) runs as expected on my machine using `Python 3.2.4 (default, May 10 2013, 08:57:38) [GCC 4.7.3] on linux2`.

Comment: @DarioTurini I added the actual output of the script.

Comment: @DarioTurini Have you patched the `__get__`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37282/discussion-between-dario-turini-and-hyperboreus)

Comment: If using python 2, you need to define it as `class DateAttribute():` to ensure it's new-style.